Trying to connect from Open SSH on my Mac
I repeatedly get these errors when trying to  set up my OpenSSH environment on my Mac.
sh/known_hosts: Permission denied
The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-174-166-107.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.174.166.107)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:EvaawFoJ54XgUbaGbUXft5t1qUlbMl1rNnSWtsBj4Uw.

This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
I am working in AmazonAWS.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1012-aws x86_64)

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-1012-aws x86_64)

Presumably sh/known_hosts is really something like /home/yourname/.ssh/known_hosts - what are the permissions and ownership on that file?
